# Ajax call does not happen synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I make a call with Ajax to an IP with some arguments. 
Before the call that matters (lets call that "call 2") can be executed, it has to make an Ajax call to get a sessionId (and lets call that "call 1"). The sessionId is necessary to make any call to the IP and have it do something with the arguments. 
But when I have the function below each other, it first does "call 2" and after that "call 1". 
 Classic async behavior but since in the Ajax call I say `async: false`, I don't really understand why it isn't doing what I say it has to do.

Complete Ajax Call "call 1":

```
Url = "_ip_?action=getsessionid";
$.ajax({

    url: Url,

    type: "Post",

    dataType: "jsonp",

    async: false,

    success: function( json ){
        var j = $.parseJSON(json);
        var sessionid = j['sessionId'];
    },

    error: function( errorThrown ) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

And Ajax call "call 2":

```
Url = "_ip_?action=action&sessionId=" + sessionid;
$.ajax({

    url: Url,

    type: "Post",

    dataType: "jsonp",

    async: false,

    success: function( json ){
        var j = JSON.parse(json);
        //do something with j
    },

    error: function( errorThrown ) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Just assume variable sessionid does give the sessionid to "call 2".
As you can see, I get an json string returned.

What I did now is that the next Ajax call only gets initialized and executed when the first Ajax call was successfully executed. This seems a workaround to me and not a proper way to do what I try to accomplish.

Comment: You should really check this specific need. Because synchronous ajax is a bad practice and maybe your browser is not doing it anymore.

Comment: You can create function for Call 2 and call it from success of Call 1 with sessionid as a parameter ....

Comment: @RafaelGuerreiro Now that i'm looking at the Ajax documation again, It has changed. "**As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().**". Thanks <br> **Edit:** it says that cross domain requests like "jsonp" which I'm using does not support synchronous operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from JQuery.ajax documentaton:

> Cross-domain requests and **dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.** Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

With that. My solution is to make the next ajax request inside the success function. The JQuery documentation explains this more. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

Define var sessionid as global variable and assign the value to the same in ajax call1 and then access this value in call2.

```
var sessionid='';
Url = "_ip_?action=getsessionid";
$.ajax({

    url: Url,

    type: "Post",

    dataType: "jsonp",

    async: false,

    success: function( json ){
        var j = $.parseJSON(json);
        sessionid = j['sessionId'];
    },

    error: function( errorThrown ) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: As I said in my question, It does call 2 first and than call 1. But the variable gets a value in call 1. So in call 2 it does not have a variable and nothing will happen.

Comment: it is not getting value because you have defined it in call one. So u have to define that variable globally so that you can use it in call2 and it will have a value assigned in call1

Comment: Just to quote myself  "Just assume variable sessionid does give the sessionid to "call 2"." That was not the problem in the first case. Tho, I have found the problem. and found a workaround to it